# How to retrieve first and 2nd element of List inside Array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, list

I'm pretty new to Java, and currently build client program based on Android.

I have backend server written in Python that will produce result containing some List inside Array.

Here is result from python I should get:

```
[[id, shopName], [id, shopName], ...]
```

Example:

```
[[1, Jakarta], [2, Bali], ...]
```

Basically, I need to have String[] containing id, and String[] containing name, for spinner adapter.

```
String[] shopServId, shopServName;
List arrayListShopServId, arrayListShopServName;

// in onCreate()
arrayListShopServId = new ArrayList();
arrayListShopServName = new ArrayList();
```

and on XMLRPCCallback listener onResponse()

```
Object[] classObjs = (Object[]) result;
int length = classObjs.length;
shopServId = new String[classObjs.length];
shopServName = new String[classObjs.length];
if ( length > 0) {
    arrayListShopServId.clear();
    arrayListShopServName.clear();
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String,Object> classObj = (Map<String,Object>)classObjs[i];
        arrayListShopServId.add(classObj.get("id"));
        arrayListShopServName.add(classObj.get("name"));
        // id and name here are object fields key to get by using XMLRPC
        shopServId[i] = arrayListShopServId.get(i).toString();
        shopServName[i] = arrayListShopServName.get(i).toString();
    }
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            loadSpinnerSaleShop();
        }
    });
} else {
    System.out.println("SaleShop not found!");
}
```

But it gives me an error
`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.util.Map`

How can I achieve that?

**EDIT**

For those who want to know, I use [XMLRPC AsynTask.](https://github.com/gturri/aXMLRPC/blob/master/README.md#asynchronous-calls)

Full part of the relevant code:

TaskId:

```
private void readSaleShop() {
    readSaleShopTaskId = util.soe_salesman_shops(listener, database, uid, password, "sale.order",
            employeeId);
}
```

The Listener:

```
XMLRPCCallback listener = new XMLRPCCallback() {
    public void onResponse(long id, Object result) {

        Looper.prepare();

        if(id==readSaleShopTaskId) {
            Object[] classObjs = (Object[]) result;
            int length = classObjs.length;
            shopServId = new String[classObjs.length];
            shopServName = new String[classObjs.length];
            if ( length > 0) {
                arrayListShopServId.clear();
                arrayListShopServName.clear();
                for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    Map<String,Object> classObj = (Map<String,Object>)classObjs[i];
                    arrayListShopServId.add(classObj.get("id"));
                    arrayListShopServName.add(classObj.get("name"));
                    shopServId[i] = arrayListShopServId.get(i).toString();
                    shopServName[i] = arrayListShopServName.get(i).toString();
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        loadSpinnerSaleShop();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                System.out.println("SaleShop not found!");
            }

        } else if(id==updateSaleOrderTaskId) {
            final Boolean updateResult =(Boolean)result;

            if(updateResult)
            {
                Log.v("SO UPDATE", "successfully");
                util.MessageDialog(SOFormActivity.this,
                        "Update SO succeed.");
            }
            else{
                util.MessageDialog(SOFormActivity.this,
                        "Update SO failed. Server return was false");
            }
        } else if (id == createSOTaskId) {

            String createResult = result.toString();
            if(createResult != null)
            {
                Log.v("SO CREATE", "successfully");
                util.MessageDialog(SOFormActivity.this,
                        "Create SO succeed. ID = " + createResult);
            }
            else
            {
                util.MessageDialog(SOFormActivity.this,
                        "Create SO failed. Server return was false");
            }
        }


        Looper.loop();
    }

    public void onError(long id, XMLRPCException error) {
        Looper.prepare();
        Log.e("SOForm", error.getMessage());
        util.MessageDialog(SOFormActivity.this, error.getMessage());
        Looper.loop();
    }

    public void onServerError(long id, XMLRPCServerException error) {
        Looper.prepare();
        Log.e("SOForm", error.getMessage());
        util.MessageDialog(SOFormActivity.this, error.getMessage());
        Looper.loop();
    }
};
```

method I use from UtilAsync class:

```
public long soe_salesman_shops(XMLRPCCallback listener, String db, String uid, String password,
                               String object, String employeeId) {
    long id = client.callAsync(listener, "execute", db, Integer.parseInt(uid), password, object,
            "soe_salesman_shops", Integer.parseInt(employeeId));
    return id;
}
```

Comment: Could you give more error output?

Comment: @Nurzhan `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2893
                  Process: com.ati.opentoko, PID: 23851
                  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.util.Map
                      at com.ati.opentoko.SOFormActivity$1.onResponse(SOFormActivity.java:246)
                      at de.timroes.axmlrpc.XMLRPCClient$Caller.run(XMLRPCClient.java:582)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up changing my python code so it will produce result List of Python Dictionary like this

```
[{'id':id, 'name':name}, {'id':id, 'name':name}, ...}]
```

So my code is working now.
But still confuse how to get certain element from List inside List.

So, if someone have working solution, I'll mark that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behavior.
You have :

```
Object[] classObjs = (Object[]) result;
Map<String,Object> classObj = (Map<String,Object>)classObjs[i];
```

You're trying to cast an Object[] element (classObjs[i]) to a different type  (Map).

You have to construct the element of the classObj Map in a proper way.

Comment: by how? could you give me an example?

Comment: In python, it is List of Lists.

Comment: actually that is the full code I'm handling the result. I've successfully getting result from List or Python Dictionary. But no clue in Java retrieving List of Lists. I've edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

`classObjs[i]` is a an object array. What you can do is cast it to an Array and then get the required data:

```
Object[] classObj = (Object[])classObjs[i];
arrayListShopServId.add(classObj[0]);
arrayListShopServName.add(classObj[1]);
```

Comment: now classObj containing 2 object (id, name), I thought perfect. `arrayListShopServId.add(classObj[0]);` gives me the id. but `arrayListShopServName.add(classObj[1]);` didn't give me the name. it gives me an error. `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
                      at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                      at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)`

Answer (score 0):

Your result is a Object[][], so you can do

`classObj.put(classObjs[i][0], classObjs[i][1]);`

But you can directly do

```
arrayListShopServId.add(classObjs[i][0]);
arrayListShopServName.add(classObjs[i][1]);
```

Comment: I can't cast the result to Object[][], It says `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.Object[][]`. I use this XMLRPC library [aXMLRPC](https://github.com/gturri/aXMLRPC/blob/master/README.md#asynchronous-calls)